# accessing id as array in ajax(php)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

friends.I am stuck with some javascript function to read keyup function to a text field with id as array(qty[]).Please help me

```
    <table id="dynamic">
    <tr>
    <td>
    <label for="textfield">product :</label>
    </td><td> <select name="product" id="product[0]">
    <?php 
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `product`");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>
    <option value=" <?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></option>
    <?php }?>
    </select>
    <label for="qty">Qty :</label>
    <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty[0]"/>
    <label for="textfield">Price :</label>
    <input type="text" name="price" id="price[0]" readonly/>
    <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button>
    </td> <div id="loader"></div></tr>
    </table>
```

*javascript*

*appending dynamic fields*

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      var i=1;
      $('#add').click(function(){
          $('#dynamic').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><label for="textfield">product :</label></td><td><select name="product" id="product['+i+']"><?php $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `product`");while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){?><option value=" <?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></option><?php }?></select><label for="qty">Qty :</label><input type="text" name="qty" id="qty['+i+']"/><label for="textfield">Price :</label><input type="text" name="price" id="price['+i+']" readonly/></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove" id="'+i+'">X</button></td></td><div id="loader"></div></tr>');
      i++;
      });
      $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
         var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
         $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
    });  


  });
  </script>
```

here i tried to access the qty[0] variable.but its not working.When its not array working fine.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function()
     {
         var i=1;
         $("#qty[0]").keyup(function()
         {

               var qty=$("#qty[0]").val();
               var pdt=$("#product[0]").val();
              i++; 

               $.ajax({

                  type:"POST",
                  url:"price_ajax.php",
                  data : { qty : qty, pdt : pdt },

                  beforeSend: function () { 
          $('#loader').html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="" width="24" height="24">');
      },
                  success:function(data)
                  {

                        $("#price[0]").val(data);
                        $("#loader").html("");
                  }
               });
         });

   });
```

Comment: Why are you providibg id like this : qty[0] ?

Comment: Try modifying the id to something like qty_0. I am sure, that will work.

Comment: i have to append dynamic fields so in order to distinguish the field i used array as id

Comment: In that case provide id like qty_0, qty_1 and so on and use it with in loop

Comment: @BhavikShah but i have more dynamic fields with same name..so how i distinguish them

Comment: Guys i gone edit question

Comment: @BhavikShah,@MayankPandey :guys please check..

Answer (score 1):

Update your code as mentioned below:

**HTML Changes:**

Add class `class='qty'` in input box in `id="qty[0]"` field

```
 $('#add').click(function(){
              $('#dynamic').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><label for="textfield">product :</label></td><td><select name="product" id="product['+i+']"><?php $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `product`");while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){?><option value=" <?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></option><?php }?></select><label for="qty">Qty :</label><input type="text" name="qty" class="qty" id="qty['+i+']"/><label for="textfield">Price :</label><input type="text" name="price" id="price['+i+']" readonly/></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove" id="'+i+'">X</button></td></td><div id="loader"></div></tr>');
          i++;

      $( ".qty" ).each(function( index ) {
         $(this).keyup(function() {
        // your code here
       });
      });
          });
```

**Jquery Changes:**

```
$( ".qty" ).each(function( index ) {
    $(this).keyup(function() {
        // your code here
    });
});
```

Comment: Replace $('#add').click() with code I provided above and try it.

Comment: Also make JQuery changes

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$('#add').click(function() {
  $('#dynamic').append('... id="product['+i+']">...');
  i++;
});
```

To

```
$('#add').click(function() {
  $('#dynamic').append('... id="product_'+i+'">...');
  i++;
});
```

`id="product[0]"` will become `id="product_0"`

Apply same method to other dynamic elements and make relevant modifications in your jQuery selector.
Everything will work fine.

Also, I would like to add here that, please break up your `append` call. Javascript, HTML and PHP, everything is happening in one single line. Which is very confusing. Prepare an HTML in javascript variable. Once done, append it.

Comment: I have demonstrated usage with `project_`. Have you made required changes for `qty`?

Comment: I modified qty[0] (not dynamic) to qty_0 as you said.Then i used  $("#qty_0").keyup(function() .but ajax not working

Comment: Are you trying to enter quantity in text field with `id=qty_0`? and still `$("#qty_0").keyup(function()..` is not working?

Comment: its working on jsfiddle..   https://jsfiddle.net/sibyxaviery2k/etq84L3b/

Comment: Then, there should be some other problem which is not allowing this function to be executed. Please check console.log and make sure that you have to syntax errors. Also, just verify that its `qty_0` and not `qty_O`. Or post the error here.

Comment: @SibyXavier: Has this worked? Have you been able to find the problem and solve it?

Comment: now $("#qty_0").keyup(function() working  but how to access others  $("#qty_+'i'").keyup(function()  does this works?

Comment: If its static, try `$(document).on("#qty_1", 'keyup', function()..`. Otherwise, add class `qty-class` and use that selector instead like this `$(document).on("#qty_1", 'keyup', function()..`.